# All buttons in <form> are posting

Tags: html

I have a `form` with multiple `textboxes` and `buttons`. I want to use some of the buttons to clear the `textbox`. But when I click on the button `Clear text` the form gets posted.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="ClearText1();">Clear text</button><br />

  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="ClearText2();">Clear text</button><br />

  <button class="btn btn-block btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use `<button type="submit" `for submit button and  `<button type="button"` for other buttons

Comment: @XYZ that was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `<button type="submit"` for submit button and `<button type="button"` for other button.You can read More  about button here.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

The type attribute of the button. Possible values are:

1. **submit**: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
2. **reset**: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
3. **button**: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
4. **menu**: The button opens a popup menu defined via its designated  element.

```html
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./send.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ClearText1();">Clear text</button><br />

  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ClearText2();">Clear text</button><br />

  <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  event.preventDefault(); to prevent default submit behavior for this button.

```
<script>
        function ClearText2(event){
            // your code....
             event.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
```